# Only authors and year being displayed when hovering over citation

Tags: hyperref, citing

When I hover over a citation number in my pdf a yellow popup appears showing the authors and the year of publishing, as can be seen from this picture:
[image: citation missing title]
However I'd like the popup to display the title of the reference as well. How can I do that?

Some additional info: The corresponding entry in the `egbib.bib` file looks like this:

```
@inproceedings{he2017mask,
    author = "He, Kaiming and Gkioxari, Georgia and Doll{\'a}r, Piotr and Girshick, Ross",
    booktitle = "{Computer Vision (ICCV), 2017 IEEE International Conference on}",
    organization = "IEEE",
    pages = "2980--2988",
    title = "{Mask r-cnn}",
    year = "2017"
}
```

The document class being used is `\documentclass{bmvc2k}` (BMVC style), 
The corresponding `bmvc2k.cls` file contains the following lines, which might be part of the problem:

```
% hook into the natbib/hyperref citation hooks.
\ifbmv@extabs\else
\ifbmv@pdf
\newbox\bmv@citebox
\let\hyper@natlinkend=\relax
\def\hyper@natlinkstart#1{%^
  \Hy@backout{#1}%^
  \xdef\bmv@annotation{\NAT@all@names\space\NAT@date}%^
  \message{BMVC cite \bmv@annotation}%^
  %\fbox{\bmv@annotation}%^
  \bmv@annottrue%^
  \hyper@linkstart{cite}{cite.#1}%^
  \bmv@annotfalse%^
  \def\hyper@nat@current{#1}%^
}

\def\hyper@natlinkend{%^
  \Hy@endcolorlink %^
%\pdfendlink
}
\fi
\fi
```